# iOS7 SpriteKit how to rotate scene to landscape on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios7, orientation, landscape, sprite-kit

I'm looking at this [sprite kit tutorial from Ray Wenderleich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners) and has downloaded the sample game that comes with tutorial.

**How can I make the scene load and lay out its nodes using the landscape coordinate system?**

While that demo appears to run in landscape, after some testing I found that the scene in tutorial still thinks it is 1024 pixels high (as opposed to 768):

```
    self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];

    DLog(@"middle: x%.2f y: %.2f",self.player.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2 );
    //middle: x13.50 y: 512.00
    DLog(@"bottom: x%.2f y: %.2f",self.player.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/4 );
   //bottom: x13.50 y: 256.00 

    //this makes the figure appear at the very bottom of the screen
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(self.player.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/4);
    [self addChild:self.player];
```

Comment: Found the answer here: http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions/ . The solution is to move scene setup code to viewWillLayoutSubviews

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial might help:

http://www.ymc.ch/en/ios-7-sprite-kit-setting-up-correct-scene-dimensions

The standard template uses the wrong method to set the scene up!